# convert javascript object to model in backbone

Tags: javascript, object, backbone.js, model

is there any way to parse object in javascript to model in Backbone.js
here is my object

[image: javascript object]

Comment: The docs explain this: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can do

```
model = new YourModel(your_object)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
new Backbone.Model({familyLogin: 'userLogin1', login: 'eg'});
```